# Automapper in web form application

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, automapper

I have a `.net` web application, I want to migrate `Automapper` to the `automapper 6` version.
My problem that when I use nuget to install `Automapper 6`, `automapper version 1.1.0` is installed by default

[image: Automapper]

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework does your project use? AutoMapper v1.1 was the last version to support.net v2.0/3.5

Answer (score 0):

Before installing from NuGet manager please check version number. As on Nov 10, 2017 Latest stable version is 6.2.0. please find the screen shot

[image]

Suppose if Automapper already been installed at your local machine, you would have get an update button under install button. So, update it.

If nothing works, uninstall Automapper and re-install it to latest version using NuGet package manager. :)

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you are seeing in NuGet?

Comment: Yup!! its right.. that makes sense. @GhassenBOUZID can you please post your screen shot.

Answer (score -1):

That indicate that `Automapper 6` is installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRV9E.png)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing an answer with more information